# Basic sql query problem

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario: lets say I have a database named `sqlprac` that contains a table named `dept`.

There are two ways to write a query:

```
use sqlprac
/*1*/
SELECT dept.deptno,
       dept.deptname,
       dept.deptsal
FROM   dept;

/*2*/
SELECT deptno,
       deptname,
       deptsal
FROM   dept;
```

Both queries should return the same result set. However I have seen that this isn't always the case, especially in sub query/inner query. What's the difference then?

Why should I choose one over another?

Also, a third query might be

```
/*3*/
SELECT *
FROM dept
```

I know what `*` is doing, but in which case we should or not use it.

Are there any performance/optimization issues?

Comment: This question should be moved to stackoverflow.com

Comment: There's three questions here: 1) what is the effect of not indicating scope, 2) why you should choose one form over another and 3) performance issues when using a particular form.  I'd recommend that the question be split up among these three lines and *asked separately*.  That way, more concise answers can be given and then addressed separately

Comment: I'm closing this until we hear back from you about splitting the question up and rephrasing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your queries are shorthand for this:

```
SELECT dept.deptno AS deptno, 
       dept.deptname AS deptname, 
       dept.deptsal AS deptname 
  FROM dept AS dept;
```

SQL is sometimes forgiving and will imply the AS clauses and correlation names, other times it requires them for no logical reason e.g.

```
SELECT deptno
  FROM dept JOIN emp USING (deptno);
```

will complain that `deptno` is ambiguous

```
SELECT deptno
  FROM (SELECT deptno FROM dept);
```

will complain that the derived table has no correlation name.

To answer the question: would would include, omit or revise the default correlation name to make the code to aid the human coder -- easier to read and understand means it will be  easier to maintain -- but tastes vary (when the same table is involved in a query more than once then you need to used an alternative correlation name to disambiguate for the purposes of the parser, obviously).

Comment: Perhaps make it clear that "no logical reason" flows from the USING because *of course" `deptno` is the same. The ambiguity would be bleeding obvious if this was `LEFT JOIN .. ON ..`. However, isn't consistency better? So the choice of which `deptno` to choose doesn't depend on which JOIN construct is used...